# Can I conditionally compile my Rust program for a Windows subsystem?

Tags: windows, compilation, rust

I have a Rust program that I want to compile for the "windows" subsystem when I'm building it for distribution. Currently I am using this in my main.rs:

```
#![feature(windows_subsystem)]
#![windows_subsystem = "windows"]
```

This works, but when I run the tests on a Windows machine, the Windows subsystem does not have access to the console so I cannot see the output. I need to comment out the above lines of code in order to see the result of my tests.

Is there a way to conditionally compile which subsystem I'm running on in order to get the tests to work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As described in [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/conditional-compilation.html), specifically the [chapter on conditional compilation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/conditional-compilation.html):

> You can also set another attribute based on a `cfg` variable with `cfg_attr`:
>
> ```
> #[cfg_attr(a, b)]
> ```
>
> Will be the same as `#[b]` if `a` is set by `cfg` attribute, and
>   nothing otherwise.

In this case, it should be something like

```
#![cfg_attr(my_feature_name_i_made_up, windows_subsystem = "windows")]
```

Comment: Sweet! it worked. The working code looks like this:

    #![feature(windows_subsystem)] 
    #![cfg_attr(not(test), windows_subsystem = "windows")]
    #![cfg_attr(test, windows_subsystem = "console")]