# Is there a way to import macros from an external crate during tests only, without any warnings?

Tags: rust

I have something like:

```
#[macro_use] extern crate log;

pub fn do_nothing() { let _ = log::Level::Info; }

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    #[test]
    fn test_a() { debug!("Message."); }
}
```

this compiles with a warning:

```
warning: unused `#[macro_use]` import
```

If I remove the macro import, and change the 1st line to:

```
extern crate log;
```

then I get the following error at compile time:

```
error: cannot find macro `debug!` in this scope
```

If I then try and import the macros only for the tests module, i.e.:

```
extern crate log;

pub fn do_nothing() { let _ = log::Level::Info; }

#[cfg(test)]

mod tests {
    #[macro_use] extern crate log;
    #[test]
    fn test_a() { debug!("Message."); }
}
```

then I get the compiler error:

```
error[E0468]: an `extern crate` loading macros must be at the crate root
```

Is there a solution which avoids all warnings without just suppressing them?

Comment: Why don't you do `#[cfg(test)] #[macro_use] extern crate log;`?

Comment: @Boiethios I think he's using `log` outside tests too, but without macros.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `cfg_attr`:

```
#[cfg_attr(test, macro_use)]
extern crate log;
```

See also:

- [Is it possible to conditionally derive with features?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42551113/155423)
- [Can I conditionally compile my Rust program for a Windows subsystem?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43744379/155423)
- [Run additional tests by using a feature flag to "cargo test"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48583049/155423)

Comment: Handy; definitely much nicer than two separate imports.